# Android - Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

i'm stuck on a problem trying to call a method from another class (when ever I call a method from this class I get a crash with NullPointerException except from when it's a static function. I currently call render.Update() and get a logcat output of -> http://pastebin.com/njjxDiQZ

```
11-26 17:14:40.532: E/MediaPlayer(29755): Should have subtitle controller already set
11-26 17:14:40.752: E/AndroidRuntime(29755): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 17:14:40.752: E/AndroidRuntime(29755): Process: com.coursework.courseworkapp, PID: 29755
11-26 17:14:40.752: E/AndroidRuntime(29755): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 17:14:40.752: E/AndroidRuntime(29755):    at com.coursework.courseworkapp.Visual.updateVisualizer(Visual.java:73)
11-26 17:14:40.752: E/AndroidRuntime(29755):    at com.coursework.courseworkapp.Visual$1.onWaveFormDataCapture(Visual.java:48)
11-26 17:14:40.752: E/AndroidRuntime(29755):    at android.media.audiofx.Visualizer$NativeEventHandler.handleCaptureMessage(Visualizer.java:669)
11-26 17:14:40.752: E/AndroidRuntime(29755):    at android.media.audiofx.Visualizer$NativeEventHandler.handleMessage(Visualizer.java:700)
11-26 17:14:40.752: E/AndroidRuntime(29755):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-26 17:14:40.752: E/AndroidRuntime(29755):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 17:14:40.752: E/AndroidRuntime(29755):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-26 17:14:40.752: E/AndroidRuntime(29755):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 17:14:40.752: E/AndroidRuntime(29755):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-26 17:14:40.752: E/AndroidRuntime(29755):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-26 17:14:40.752: E/AndroidRuntime(29755):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-26 17:14:40.752: E/AndroidRuntime(29755):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help would be appreciated i'm really stumped here.

## First Class

```
package com.coursework.courseworkapp;

import java.util.Set;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.audiofx.Visualizer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Visual{
byte[] fft;
byte[] mFFTBytes;
byte[] mBytes;
private Visualizer mVisualizer;
Render render;
private Rect mRect = new Rect();

private Paint mFlashPaint = new Paint();
private Paint mFadePaint = new Paint();

Bitmap mCanvasBitmap;
Canvas mCanvas;



public int Test(MediaPlayer player){

    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(player.getAudioSessionId());
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
    Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener captureListener = new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
          int samplingRate)
      {
          updateVisualizer(bytes);

      }

      @Override
      public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
          int samplingRate)
      {
        updateVisualizerFFT(bytes);

      }
    };

    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(captureListener, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, true);
    mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);



    return player.getAudioSessionId();

}

public void updateVisualizer(byte[] bytes) {
        mBytes = bytes;
    }


public void updateVisualizerFFT(byte[] bytes) {
    mFFTBytes = bytes;
        render.Update();
        //render.invalidate()           
    }

    public byte[] getFFT(){
        return mFFTBytes;  
    }
}
```

## The Render Class

```
package com.coursework.courseworkapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.audiofx.Visualizer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Render extends View {

public Render(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setMinimumWidth(800);
    setMinimumHeight(1000);
    setFocusable(true);
}

public void Update(){
    //Will have code here after fix crash.

}
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){           
    canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);        
    //Will add more code here.
}
}
```

## MainActivity.Java - How I start Visualise.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
Visual visualize = new Visual();
Render render;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    render = new Render(this);
    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root)).addView(render, 0);

    //Log.d("Freq", "test");
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test2);
    mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mPlayer.start();
    //Log.d("Freq", "test");
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int i = visualize.Test(mPlayer);
            //render.invalidate();


        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);

    /*byte[] fft = visualize.getFFT();
    if(fft != null){
        Toast.makeText(this,"yey",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"nope",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }*/

    /* THis part didn't work, Why? Check the other example */
    //Log.w("Freq", String.valueOf(fft.length));
    /*for(int i = 0; i < fft.length; i++){
        String s = new String();
        Log.w("Freq", String.valueOf(fft[i]));

    }*/
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void tryDraw(){
    //render.Update();
}
```

}

Comment: post the logcat here.

Comment: IT seems to be happening as `bytes` are null.

Comment: what is line 73 `Visual.java`?.

Comment: I've tried checking if bytes != null then calling the function but it still occurs. Line 73 is, render.update();

Comment: @user3037567 where is visualize initialized before calling `visualize.Test(mPlayer)` and where is `rende`r initialized before calling `render.update()`?

Comment: I've added the whole code of all 3 classes. A lot of the code is eddited from, [Here](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer) .

Answer (score 0):

Your visual class does not extend Activtiy. But you have

```
 render = new Render(this);
```

`this` does not refer to Activity Context.

Also you are not inflating any layoutin visual class `((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root)).addView(render, 0);` will give you `NullPointerException`.

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id mentioned in the current inflated layout.

Comment: Hmm, sorry for asking this as i'm fairly new to Java programming but in theory adding 'extends Activity' to the Visual class should help with my problem?

Just quickly tried and I'm still left with the same crash unfortunately but I may have misunderstood what you meant or is there a way to refer to the context other than this?

Comment: Basically I agree. But shouldn't this error not be detected by the compiler?

Comment: Sorry again for being such a pain, I actually had the `render = new Render(this);
  ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root)).addView(render, 0);` 

in MainActivity.java but was pasting it around trying to work out the problem, I forgot to change it back.

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.root)` will fail if you don't inflate a layout. Also you need to refer to Activity context. `this` in your case does not refer to activity context.

Comment: @user3037567 now which line causes NPE after updating?

Comment: Ok, sorry for a long reply time. Still the same line causing the problem, `render.Update();` I changed the things you mentioned moving some of the code to MainActivity.java which runs Visual.java using, a handler and a runnable (eddited code above to include that part of MainActivity.java)

Comment: @user3037567 its simple render is null. its not initialiazed properly. and its a activity context `render = new Render(ActivityName.this)`. then call `render.update()`

Comment: It doesn't seem to resolve `ActivityName.this`, I've tried with multiple ways of passing context that I know of such as `getActivityContext` but they also cause crashes. I know i'm just being stupid now but i'm finding it difficult to grasp the idea of context.

Comment: @user3037567 problem is `render.Update()` is in Visual class not Activity class. render is not initialized in visual class. you need to pass activtiy context to the constructor of visual class then initialize render then call `render.update()`

Comment: @user3037567 i suggest you read the docs and get to know the basics.

Comment: Thanks i'll have a look over them, the topic I can find on Contexts isn't great but i'll do my best. From what your saying though I need to pass the context from `MainActivity.java` to `Visual.java` which is then used to initialize `Render render = new Render(context)`

Answer (score 0):

You declare `Render render;` but don't initialize it 
You can do this only if render is static so fix that

**VISUAL:**

```
public class Visual {

Context mContext;

// constructor
public Visual(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    }

....

public void updateVisualizerFFT(byte[] bytes) {
    mFFTBytes = bytes;
        //Don't forget to initialize redender
        Render render = new Render(this.mContext);
        render.Update();
        //render.invalidate()           
    }
}
```

**RENDER:**

```
public class Render extends View {

public Render(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setMinimumWidth(800);
    setMinimumHeight(1000);
    setFocusable(true);
}

}
```

**MainActivity :**

You should be able to run

```
int i = visualize.Test(mPlayer);
```

Read up on [context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)